# How to extract tags from HTML using Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to parse through an HTML page which simplified looks like this:

```
<div class="anotherclass part"
  <a href="http://example.com" >
    <div class="column abc"><strike>&#163;3.99</strike><br>&#163;3.59</div>
    <div class="column def"></div>
    <div class="column ghi">1 Feb 2013</div>
    <div class="column jkl">
      <h4>A title</h4>
      <p>
        <img class="image" src="http://example.com/image.jpg">A, List, Of, Terms, To, Extract - 1 Feb 2013</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am a beginner at coding python and I have read and re-read the beautifulsoup documentation at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

I have got this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open("file.html") as fp:
  html = fp.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

parts = soup.findAll('a', attrs={"class":re.compile('part'), re.IGNORECASE} )
for part in parts:
  mypart={}

  # ghi
  mypart['ghi'] = part.find(attrs={"class": re.compile('ghi')} ).string
  # def
  mypart['def'] = part.find(attrs={"class": re.compile('def')} ).string
  # h4
  mypart['title'] = part.find('h4').string

  # jkl
  mypart['other'] = part.find('p').string

  # abc
  pattern = re.compile( r'\&\#163\;(\d{1,}\.?\d{2}?)' )
  theprices = re.findall( pattern, str(part) )
  if len(theprices) == 2:
    mypart['price'] = theprices[1]
    mypart['rrp'] = theprices[0]
  elif len(theprices) == 1:
    mypart['price'] = theprices[0]
    mypart['rrp'] = theprices[0]
  else:
    mypart['price'] = None
    mypart['rrp'] = None
```

I want to extract any text from the classes `def` and `ghi` which I think my script does correctly.

I also want to extract the two prices from `abc` which my script does in a rather clunky fashion at the moment.  Sometimes there are two prices, sometimes one and sometimes none in this part.

Finally I want to extract the `"A, List, Of, Terms, To, Extract"` part from class `jkl` which my script fails to do.  I thought getting the string part of the `p` tag would work but I cannot understand why it does not.  The date in this part always matches the date in class `ghi` so it should be easy to replace/remove it.

Any advice?  Thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you add `convertEntities=bs.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES` to

```
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=bs.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

then the html entities such as `&#163;` will be converted to their corresponding unicode character, such as `£`. This will allow you to use a simpler regex to identify the prices.

---

Now, given `part`, you can find the text content in the `<div>` with the prices using its `contents` attribute:

```
In [37]: part.find(attrs={"class": re.compile('abc')}).contents
Out[37]: [<strike>£3.99</strike>, <br />, u'\xa33.59']
```

All we need to do is extract the number from each item, or skip it if there is no number:

```
def parse_price(text):
    try:
        return float(re.search(r'\d*\.\d+', text).group())
    except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
        return None

price = []
for item in part.find(attrs={"class": re.compile('abc')}).contents:
    item = parse_price(item.string)
    if item:
        price.append(item)
```

At this point `price` will be a list of 0, 1, or 2 floats.
We would like to say

```
mypart['rrp'], mypart['price'] = price
```

but that would not work if `price` is `[]` or contains only one item.

Your method of handling the three cases with `if..else` is okay -- it is the most straightforward and arguably the most readable way to proceed. But it is also a bit mundane. If you'd like something a little more terse you could do the following:

Since we want to repeat the same price if `price` contains only one item, you might be led to think about [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

In the case where `price` is the empty list, `[]`, we want `itertools.cycle([None])`, but otherwise we could use `itertools.cycle(price)`.

So to combine both cases into one expression, we could use

```
price = itertools.cycle(price or [None])
mypart['rrp'], mypart['price'] = next(price), next(price)
```

The `next` function peels off the values in the iterator `price` one by one. Since `price` is cycling through its values, it will never end; it will just keep yielding the values in sequence and then starting over again if necessary -- which is just what we want.

---

The `A, List, Of, Terms, To, Extract - 1 Feb 2013` could be obtained again through the use of the `contents` attribute:

```
# jkl
mypart['other'] = [item for item in part.find('p').contents
                   if not isinstance(item, bs.Tag) and item.string.strip()]
```

---

So, the full runnable code would look like:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import re
import itertools as IT

def parse_price(text):
    try:
        return float(re.search(r'\d*\.\d+', text).group())
    except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
        return None

filename = os.path.expanduser("~/tmp/file.html")
with open(filename) as fp:
    html = fp.read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=bs.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

for part in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": re.compile('(?i)part')}):
    mypart = {}
    # abc
    price = []
    for item in part.find(attrs={"class": re.compile('abc')}).contents:
        item = parse_price(item.string)
        if item:
            price.append(item)

    price = IT.cycle(price or [None])
    mypart['rrp'], mypart['price'] = next(price), next(price)

    # jkl
    mypart['other'] = [item for item in part.find('p').contents
                       if not isinstance(item, bs.Tag) and item.string.strip()]

    print(mypart)
```

which yields

```
{'price': 3.59, 'other': [u'A, List, Of, Terms, To, Extract - 1 Feb 2013'], 'rrp': 3.99}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution unutbu :-) Thank-you very much for your time and effort.  There is a lot there for me to digest and I have learnt quite a few things from your answer.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: ... can just add: really impressive effort -- let me just point you to  a tiny mistake that crept into your code: you use `item.string` inside `parse_price(text)` instead of `text`